# Is there a lodash/fp equivalent of Ramda's 'evolve' function?

Tags: javascript, lodash, ramda.js

Looking for a lodash equivalent of [Ramda's evolve](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve):

```
const transformForDisplay = (item) => {
  const transform = {
    body: truncate({ length: 100 }),
    title: truncate({ length: 50 })
  }

  return R.evolve(transform, item)
}
```

Which returns an object containing all of the original fields from 'item' but truncating the 'body' and 'title' fields if they exist.

Edit: this works. Anything more pithy?

```
const transformForDisplay = (item) => {
  const transform = {
    body: truncate,
    title: truncate
  }

  const mapValuesWithKey = _.mapValues.convert({ cap: false })
  return mapValuesWithKey((x, key) => transform[key] ? transform[key](x) : x)(item)
}
```

Comment: @Drenai it creates a new `mapValues` function that accepts the second parameter of `map` so that we can access the key in addition to the value.

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide#convert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any built-in equivalent. Here's how you might implement `evolve` yourself.

It's pretty much what you already had, except I used `_.getOr` to avoid having to repeat `transform[key]`, and I added a recursive call to `evolve` when necessary.

```js
// Implementation    

const mapValuesWithKey = _.mapValues.convert({cap: false});

function evolve(transformations) {
  return item =>
    mapValuesWithKey((value, key) => {
      const transformation = _.getOr(_.identity)(key)(transformations);
      const type = typeof transformation;
      return type === 'function' ?
        transformation(value) :
        transformation && type === 'object' ?
          evolve(transformation)(value) :
          value;
    })(item);
}

// Example    

const tomato  = {
  firstName: '  Tomato ',
  data: {elapsed: 100, remaining: 1400},
  id: 123
};
const transformations = {
  firstName: _.trim,
  lastName: _.trim, // Will not get invoked.
  data: {elapsed: _.add(1), remaining: _.add(-1)},
  id: null, // Will have no effect.
}
const result = evolve(transformations)(tomato);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.fp.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that /is/ closer to the [Ramda implementation](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/evolve.js#L31). I guess the answer is that there's no direct equivalent?

Comment: @NickCox I udpated to clarify that I don't know of any equivalent. Thanks for the link to the Ramda implementation; it exposed some corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried to use more lodash functions:

```
const evolve = _.curry((transformations, item) =>
    _.mapValues.convert({ cap: false })((value, key) => {
        const transformation = _.propOr(identity, key, transformations);

        return _.cond([
            [_.isFunction, t => t(value)],
            [_.isObject, t => evolve(t, value)],
            [_.T, _.always(value)],
        ])(transformation);
    }, item)
);
```